# How to relate the $|z^3+z^{-3}|$ with $|z+z^{-1}|$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I got stuck on this seemingly simple question:

> If $z$ is a complex number satisfying $|z^3+z^{-3}| \le 2$, then the maximum possible value of $|z+z^{-1}|$ is:
>   (A) $2$
>   (B) $2^{1/3}$
>   (C) $2\sqrt 2$
>   (D) $1$

Using the AM-GM inequality, I showed that $|z|^3 + |z|^{-3} \ge 2$ and so I got:
$$ |z^3+z^{-3}| \le 2 \le |z|^3 + |z|^{-3}$$

I don't inderstand how I can remove the cubic power, and bring any of this in terms of $|z|$ and $|z|^{-1}$. What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: As the answers below have shown, you have to use the Triangle inequality.

Answer (score 5):

We can write $$z^3+\frac{1}{z^3} = \left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^3-3\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right).$$

Given $$2 \geq \left|z^3+\frac{1}{z^3}\right| = \left|\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)^3-3\left(z+\frac{1}{z}\right)\right|\geq \left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|^3-3\left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|.$$

Now put $$\left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|=y.$$

So we get $y^3-3y\leq 2\Rightarrow y^3-3y-2\leq 0\Rightarrow y^3-4y+y-2\leq0$.

So $$\displaystyle y(y-2)(y+2)+1(y-2)\leq 0\Rightarrow (y-2)(y+1)^2\leq0.$$

So we get $$y\leq 2\Rightarrow \left|z+\frac{1}{z}\right|\leq 2$$

because $$(y+1)^2\geq 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I also liked how you factorized the cubic, how did you think of it?

Comment: Using Integral root Theorem, i have just factorize constant term $2$ as $\pm 1\;, \pm 2$ and the put $y=1$ or $y=-1$ or $y=2$ or $y=-2$ ect

Answer (score 4):

$(z+z^{-1})^3=z^3 + 3z + 3z^{-1}+z^{-3}$ therefore $|z+z^{-1}|^3 \le |z^3 + z^{-3}| + 3 |z+z^{-1}| \le 2 + 3|z+z^{-1}|$ and using notation $|z+z^{-1}| = x$ we have:

$x^3 \le 2 + 3x$ equivalent $(x-2)(x+1)^2 \le 0$ therefore $|z+z^{-1}| \le 2 $ is the answer